# Lenovo Thinkpad Keyboard T510 dimension

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop, dimensions

I am working on a project where I need the dimensions of the T510 Keyboard.

The plan is to use the Keyboard with odroid or any other micro-controller board. The easiest way is to use the usb interface and for that it should fit into my Thinkpad Edge 11.

It will probably require some minor changes and thats where its starts. I want to know the size of it before I buy it. Unfortunately the manual doesn't include dimensions of e.g. T510 specific parts: http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/63y0536.pdf

If someone owns a C989, could he/she pace it up and down for me?

Comment: I've got a T500 (same keyboard as a T60/T61) a T520 and a T530.  If any of those are the same as a T510, I'd be happy to give you dimensions.

Comment: Ok, but you need to look that up for me, though.  Which one should I measure, assuming any of those 3 are the same as the T510.  (The T530 is the chicklets keybarod, so I don't think that's what you want; but the 500 or the 520 may be.  Those two are different.)

Comment: @Diagon Comparing images the T520 looks much more like the T510 keyboard. So 520 would be my choice. Thanks in advantage!

Comment: Ya, looking at Youtube, that seems right. All the vids are for T/W510 & T/W520.  I've got the keyboard out, but the dimensions are not simple.  It's not just the mouse buttons jutting out of one side, but also there are some small areas knocked out in the top.  Let me see if I can figure out how to do this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here are the dimensions for a T520 Keyboard.  I'm looking at the bottom here, with the mouse buttons at the top of this picture (on the other side) and the edge closest to the screen (when installed) is at the bottom.

I warned you, it's not a simple rectangle!  (This is not drawn to scale.)

[image: Keyboard]

Comment: Without verifying... well done.

Comment: Well then, give me an upvote, dude!  (Trying to get to 200 so I can comment on all the SE sites...)

Comment: Thanks again that will definitely help me (I would up-vote but I am afraid I have no permissions yet :\ )

Comment: Great.  Good luck with the project ...